# How do I build a C++ application with mediapipe on Windows?

Tags: c++, build, bazel, mediapipe

I have built a prototype of my video analysis pipeline, which uses mediapipe, in python. Now I need the extra performance gains (multithreading, direct access to SIMD, etc.) from writing a native application in C++. I am developing this application on Windows.

As there doesn't seem to be any prebuilt binaries of mediapipe, I downloaded the mediapipe source code and have managed to build it using the bazel build system. The problem I am having is that I am simply unable to figure out which library files to link with from my application. What I need is either a shared library or a static library to link with. I would prefer not to build my own application through bazel.

I have tried going trough the files in the bazel-out and bazel-bin directories to see if I could find a file that seemed to be what I was looking for, but couldn't find any file that seemed promising. I also (I assumed this wouldn't work but tried it anyways) tried to use lib.exe to combine all the files in bazel-out into a single library. Unfortunately lib.exe didn't seem to like my 50K characters command.

EDIT: As it was asked for in the comments:

- System: Windows 10
- MSVC version: cl.exe prints 19.36.32535 for x64
- Bazel version: 7.0.0-pre.20230530.3
- Libraries: MediaPipe and its dependencies.

Also, I did find a workaround for my problem which was to include my source code inside of the Mediapipe source tree and build everything through Bazel. This is definitely an odd way of doing things but it does work.

Comment: You should list your system, compiler, tools and libraries used. Supply the commands you've executed to build stuff with bazel and their output. Then you need to list artifacts produced by those commands. *"unable to figure out which library files to link"*  - then you should probably ask about it as well. If you can't figure out what you want to use then how readers will figure it out?

Comment: @user7860670 System:Windows 10,compiler: msvc,tools:Bazel,Libraries: Mediapipe. I have now figured out that there is no builtin way to build all of mediapipe into a .lib or .dll file, it just builds _lots_ of small .obj/.lib files which you are supposed to use Bazel to link with. My preferred solution would be to use a static or shared library for all of mediapipe. I ended up building my application as a library inside of the Mediapipe source tree, as building it outside of the source tree is hard because you cannot easily include the dependencies of Mediapipe from an external WORKSPACE file.

Comment: msvc - which version? Bazel - which version? And all this stuff should be included in the question itself rather than into a comment. It should be there so people reading the question would be able to perform steps you've taken and obtain the same results. While bazel does tent to produce a lot of object files and achieves, usually only few of them are useful.

Comment: @user7860670 I have now updated my question. As I have a working solution I probably will not spend more time on this question, unless someone knows of a better way of using mediapipe than modifying their source tree.